# How to split one column into two using different tables?

Tags: oracle, vba

I am developing a frontend application in VBA, which is linked to an Oracle database.
In Oracle there are the two tables `Table1`and `Table2`, which are related to each other by expTypeID and measID:

```
Table1
expTypeID | measID| val
12          20001   1.1
13          20002   200
13          21043   250
12          29321   0.9
13          29322   150
15          23450   23000
```

```
Table2
expTypeID | measID | productID | productName
12          20001      100023   Apple
13          20002      100023   Apple
13          21043      129842   Pear
12          29321      198372   Orange
13          29322      198372   Orange
```

I would like to get a new table, that for all products contains the values for specific expTypeIDs in different columns, e.g expTypeID = 12 -> ""Density"" and expTypeID = 13  -> ""EModulus"":

```
GoalTable
productName | productID |   Density |   EModulus
Apple         100023          1.1         200
Pear          129842           -          250
Orange        198372          0.9         150
```

I know that it is possible when all the necessary data is available in one table: [show-one-column-data-as-two-columns-in-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28103927/show-one-column-data-as-two-columns-in-sql) (I found the query proposed by mat particularly useful). Is it still possible when the data is present in two tables?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
WITH
table1 (EXPTYPEID, MEASID, VAL) AS ( 
    SELECT 12,          20001,   1.1   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 13,          20002,   200   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 13,          21043,   250   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 12,          29321,   0.9   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 13,          29322,   150   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 15,          23450,   23000 FROM DUAL 
),
table2 (EXPTYPEID, MEASID, PRODUCTID, PRODUCTNAME) AS (
    SELECT 12,          20001,      100023,   'Apple'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 13,          20002,      100023,   'Apple'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 13,          21043,      129842,   'Pear'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 12,          29321,      198372,   'Orange' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 13,          29322,      198372,   'Orange' FROM DUAL 
),
prapare_data AS (
    SELECT t1.expTypeID, t1.measID, t1.val, t2.productID, t2.productName
    FROM table1 t1
    JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.expTypeID=t2.expTypeID AND t1.measID=t2.measID
)
SELECT productID, productName,
       MAX(CASE WHEN expTypeID = 12 THEN val END) AS Density,
       MAX(CASE WHEN expTypeID = 13 THEN val END) AS EModulus
FROM prapare_data
GROUP BY productID, productName
ORDER BY productID;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f683e33fb705a05de3a2d7e704aac634

Comment: Thanks, the query works. The problem is now that `Group By` does only include the first density - EModulus pair. In reality I have multiple E-Modulus values (e.g. measured at differnt temperature conditions with condIDs, which are stored in another table) for the same PRODUCTID. Is there a way to print every matching pair and not only the first?

Comment: @JAUGRY Group in `prapare_data` (by productID, productName and expTypeID) and aggregate E-Modulus values (val column) into single CSV string in the subquery.